# React.js and Redux drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am coding a project with react.js and redux.I have some boxes that can be dragged and dropped, the boxes can also be delete.
but if you drag and drop, they are not deleted properly.
for example, if you drag box number one and drop it in box number two,the boxes will change together,when you click on the button to delete box number two, box number one will be deleted!!
if we do not drag and drop, the deletion will be done correctly.
please guide me to solve this problem.

file reducer

```js
import { ActionType } from "../action-types";
import { Action } from "../actions";

const initialState: any = [1, 2];
const boxReducer = (state: any = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.ADDBOX:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case ActionType.DELETEBOX:
            return state.filter(function (g: any) {
                return g !== action.payload
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default boxReducer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

file drap and drop

```js
import "./style/drag-and-drop.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { actionCreators, State } from '../../state-manaement';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

function DragAndDrop() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { deleteBox } = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
    let state = useSelector((state: State) => state.box);

    const dragEnd = function (e: any) {
        var areas: any = document.querySelectorAll(".a");

        for (var area of areas) {

            if ((e.clientX > area.getBoundingClientRect().x &&
                e.clientX < area.getBoundingClientRect().x + area.clientWidth) &&
                (e.clientY > area.getBoundingClientRect().y &&
                    e.clientY < area.getBoundingClientRect().y + area.clientHeight)) {
                if (area.childElementCount === 0) {
                    let aux = area.firstElementChild;
                    e.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(aux.id));
                    console.log("area.childElementCount", area.childElementCount);
                    area.appendChild(document.getElementById(e.target.id));
                }
                if (area.childElementCount === 1) {
                    let aux = area.firstElementChild;
                    e.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(aux.id));

                    area.appendChild(document.getElementById(e.target.id));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
    return (
        <div className="grid-container">
            {
                state.map(function (item: any, index: any) {
                    return (
                        <div className="a" key={index} >
                        <div className="area" draggable="true" id={`area_${item}`}
                        >
                            <div className="box" id={`box_${item}`} >
                                <span title={item} >  
                                    <img
                                        onClick={() => { deleteBox(item); }}
                                        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/icons/trash.svg`}
                                        alt='trash-icon' />
                                </span>
                                <div className="item">{item} </div>
                            </div>
                            {item}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default DragAndDrop;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You would have much better chancing using https://dndkit.com/ or react beautifully dnd. From the description you have event triggered twice, or you set an id to the element and did not replace id on previous element